# Nuxt js - SSR page duplicates components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am generating a simple static page with a list of components and when I visit the page from another page it renders everything correctly. When I land directly on the page some of the components are rendered again after the footer. If I inspect the element I can see that they are the same elements but rendered again after the footer. Anyone has any idea on why this is happening?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <client-only>
      <MobileNav v-if="!isDesktop" />
      <Topnav v-if="isDesktop" />
      <div v-if="isDesktop">
        <Navbar active-page="consumers" />
      </div>
    </client-only>
    <Hero page="consumers" hero-text="for consumers" text-alignment="middle" />
    <AnchorNav :anchor-nav-items="anchorNavData" />

    <div id="for-consumers">
      <Highlight :data="highlight1" />
      <Highlight :data="highlight2" />
    </div>

    <LazyCardsWithModal :data="cardsList" />

    <LazyImageText :data="imageTextDirector" />

    <LazyKeyCards :data="keyCards" />

    <LazyAccordion :data="accordionData" />

    <LazyOrderedList :data="orderedList" />

    <LazyLogoCards :data="logoCards" :index="1" />
    <LazyLogoCards :data="logoCards2" :index="2" />

    <LazyCardsWithModal :data="productsCards" class="consumers-cards-2" />

    <Footer />

    <Modal
      v-show="this.$store.state.modal.active"
      :id="this.$store.state.modal.id"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

This is what the page template looks like

Comment: seems like     <Modal
      v-show="this.$store.state.modal.active"
      :id="this.$store.state.modal.id"
    />
Model after the footer is causing this issue.  Since you are using vuex state, if you refresh then the data wont be persisted. log the this.$store.state.modal.active and check it out.

Comment: thanks for the comment @Lohith, I think it makes sense. How would you approach the modal? Shall I include it in the component and not at the page level?

Comment: If the problem is really uncontrolled state data, then you can keep default value in data(){modalActive:false} , update the value with mapState, then refer modalActive in the template.

Comment: I am removing the modal functionality for now to check if it still has the issue. I will keep you posted but looks like it's related to the state data as you mentioned. One more thing I have noticed is that it works fine when I run it locally and the issue is only when it gets generated

Comment: @Lohith it didn't fix it unfortunately..so strange that this happens only on one single page..I am trying to debug removing one component at a time

Comment: Just for my clarification, for you everything works, if you run in develop mode >npm run dev.   you are facing this issue with static page after running this-> npm run generate? am i correct.

Comment: yes it works fine in develop mode (npm run dev) and the issue is only on the static page generated

Comment: I had similar issue with breadcrumbs in static mode, which i tried to handle with vuex state, i still use state functionality but to handle it i added multiple if else conditions. In your case if you are facing the issue even after removing the modal means, then it might be from some other components which i cant figure out, as the code seems too abstract to guess.

Comment: hey @Lohith confirming that was a vuex issue. I've spotted the component and wrapped it with a client-only tag and it fixed the issue. thx for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue is with vuex state management when running it as static site. which works proper when running in the develop mode.

Ways to overcome this is.

1. avoiding the direct call to state variables in the template.
2. making use of `client-only` tag which helps to avoid dom-mismatch issue.