# Duplication of elements under footer when ssr is enabled?

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

When I turn ssr on in Nuxt my dev environment doubles the information under the hero element creating a duplicate of the footer and other elements on my web page. I heard the error might be fixed through a client-only tag and that it might be an issue with the vuex state management but I am unsure how to approach this issue.

Here is the index.vue page

```html
<template>
  <header class="fixed opacity-[.98] bg-info text-base-200 z-50">
    <div class="navbar w-screen">
      <div class="flex-1">
        <NuxtLink to="/" class="absolute w-28">
          <nuxt-img
            alt="Yuuera logo"
            src="@/assets/images/logo.png"
            class="w-28 fill-current"
          />
        </NuxtLink>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-none">
        <div class="pr-4 mt-2">
          <NuxtLink to="/about"
            ><span class="text-primary text-lg font-semibold"
              >About</span
            ></NuxtLink
          >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <body class="bg-base-100">
    <section class="h-2/3 pt-24">
      <nuxt-img
        src="@/assets/images/twitter base trans.png"
        class="absolute top-7 opacity-10 z-0 lowest-el"
      />
      <div>
        <div class="flex justify-center items-center">
          <div class="hero-content text-center text-neutral-content">
            <div class="max-w-4xl sm:text-left">
              <h1 class="text-primary text-6xl md:text-9xl font-semibold">
                Who we are
              </h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="rounded-3xl bg-info z-40">
        <div class="mt-10 flex justify-center">
          <h1 class="text-primary p-4 font-bold text-4xl md:text-7xl">
            Vision
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="flex justify-center">
          <div class="p-4 md:w-2/3 rounded-3xl">
            <p
              class="text-xl text-center leading-loose tracking-widest text-l lg:text-2xl"
            >
             ...
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <div class="avatar">
        <nuxt-img src="@/assets/images/laptopstock.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center items-center mb-12">
        <div class="hero-content text-center text-neutral-content">
          <div class="max-w-4xl sm:text-left">
            <h1 class="text-primary font-bold text-4xl md:text-7xl">
              Company Story
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mt-10 mb-12 flex justify-center">
        <div class="p-4 md:w-2/3 rounded-3xl">
          <p
            class="text-xl text-center leading-loose tracking-widest text-l lg:text-2xl"
          >
            ...
            time.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <div>
        <div class="flex justify-center items-center mb-12">
          <div class="hero-content text-center text-neutral-content">
            <div class="max-w-4xl sm:text-left">
              <h1 class="text-primary font-bold text-4xl md:text-7xl">
                Our Values
              </h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex rounded-3xl bg-info p-4 mb-12 team-member flex-col">
          <div class="flex justify-center">
            <nuxt-img
              src="@/assets/images/padlock.png"
              class="margin-left-24px justify-contents"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <p class="font-medium p-8 text-2xl">Security:</p>
            <p class="font-medium text-lg">
              ...
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex rounded-3xl bg-info p-4 mb-12 h team-member flex-col">
          <div class="flex rounded">
            <nuxt-img src="@/assets/images/internet-image.png" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <p class="font-medium p-8 text-2xl">Community:</p>
            <p class="font-medium text-lg">
             ...
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex rounded-3xl bg-info p-4 team-member flex-col">
          <div class="flex rounded">
            <nuxt-img src="@/assets/images/chatbubbles.png" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <p class="font-medium p-8 text-2xl">Consumer Focused:</p>
            <p class="font-medium text-lg">
              ...
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <EmailSignUp class="pt-4 pb-4"></EmailSignUp>

    <footer class="footer footer-center p-4 bg-primary text-primary-content">
      <div>
        <p class="font-bold">... <br /></p>
        <p>YuueraOffical@gmail.com</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="grid grid-flow-col gap-4">
          <a href="https://twitter.com/..."
            ><svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="24"
              height="24"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              class="fill-current"
            >
              <path
                d="M24 4.557c-.883.392-1.832.656-2.828.775 1.017-.609 1.798-1.574 2.165-2.724-.951.564-2.005.974-3.127 1.195-.897-.957-2.178-1.555-3.594-1.555-3.179 0-5.515 2.966-4.797 6.045-4.091-.205-7.719-2.165-10.148-5.144-1.29 2.213-.669 5.108 1.523 6.574-.806-.026-1.566-.247-2.229-.616-.054 2.281 1.581 4.415 3.949 4.89-.693.188-1.452.232-2.224.084.626 1.956 2.444 3.379 4.6 3.419-2.07 1.623-4.678 2.348-7.29 2.04 2.179 1.397 4.768 2.212 7.548 2.212 9.142 0 14.307-7.721 13.995-14.646.962-.695 1.797-1.562 2.457-2.549z"
              ></path></svg
          ></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
@import 'assets/scss/appStyles.scss';
</style>
```

Ive tried moving my project to a new instance of Nuxt and updating it to Nuxt 3.6.1 but so far nothing I've tried has accomplished getting rid of the duplicate elements. Though the issue seems to go away when I disable ssr making it equal false in the nuxt.config.ts file, this fix is not for me though as I would like to use ssr in production.

Comment: have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66152901/nuxt-js-ssr-page-duplicates-components) and from I can find, it seems this is  the only solution and you have to manage your state away, if it is an option for u

Comment: I figured it would be the client-only element. Its only i don't know where it might need to be used given the state of the application. It works If I surround the whole application with the client-only element. I really want to know whats causing the issue in the first place.